# Formatting datetime column to a single format of a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am encountering a problem, where the datetime column of my monthly dataframe of contains more than one format, like lets say for example: for a month `'January'` the format in the beginning `'2020-03-13'` for `'13th March 2020'` and some rows have datetime format as `'2020-12-03`' for `'12th March 2020'` which resemble like `'1st December 2021'`, which is a big mistake as i will represent the monthly data for one full year.

```
                   date  S1counts  S1SM  ...  S10Perm  S10Temp  S10Volt
0    2020-03-13 00:08:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.164    12.09
1    2020-03-13 00:18:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.133    12.11
2    2020-03-13 00:28:08   14057.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.102    12.11
3    2020-03-13 00:38:08   14057.0  5.61  ...    12.09   22.063    12.11
4    2020-03-13 00:48:08   14060.0  5.60  ...    12.09   22.031    12.11
                 ...       ...   ...  ...      ...      ...      ...
2170 2020-12-03 23:18:08   14051.0  5.62  ...    12.11   22.313    12.11
2171 2020-12-03 23:28:08   14056.0  5.61  ...    12.11   22.266    12.11
2172 2020-12-03 23:38:08   14056.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.250    12.11
2173 2020-12-03 23:48:08   14051.0  5.62  ...    12.10   22.242    12.09
2174 2020-12-03 23:58:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.188    12.09

[2175 rows x 51 columns]
```

I have tried with `pandas.to_datetime()` with a format but the format is not changing and showing result as above.

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

An approach

- try converting using American format first
- if that gives a `NaT` fill with international format

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   date  S1counts  S1SM  ...  S10Perm  S10Temp  S10Volt
0    2020-03-13 00:08:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.164    12.09
1    2020-03-13 00:18:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.133    12.11
2    2020-03-13 00:28:08   14057.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.102    12.11
3    2020-03-13 00:38:08   14057.0  5.61  ...    12.09   22.063    12.11
4    2020-03-13 00:48:08   14060.0  5.60  ...    12.09   22.031    12.11
2170  2020-12-03 23:18:08   14051.0  5.62  ...    12.11   22.313    12.11
2171  2020-12-03 23:28:08   14056.0  5.61  ...    12.11   22.266    12.11
2172  2020-12-03 23:38:08   14056.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.250    12.11
2173  2020-12-03 23:48:08   14051.0  5.62  ...    12.10   22.242    12.09
2174  2020-12-03 23:58:08   14055.0  5.61  ...    12.10   22.188    12.09
"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce").fillna(pd.to_datetime(df.date))
```

|  | date | S1counts | S1SM | ... | S10Perm | S10Temp | S10Volt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-03-13 00:08:08 | 14055 | 5.61 | ... | 12.1 | 22.164 | 12.09 |
| 1 | 2020-03-13 00:18:08 | 14055 | 5.61 | ... | 12.1 | 22.133 | 12.11 |
| 2 | 2020-03-13 00:28:08 | 14057 | 5.61 | ... | 12.1 | 22.102 | 12.11 |
| 3 | 2020-03-13 00:38:08 | 14057 | 5.61 | ... | 12.09 | 22.063 | 12.11 |
| 4 | 2020-03-13 00:48:08 | 14060 | 5.6 | ... | 12.09 | 22.031 | 12.11 |
| 2170 | 2020-03-12 23:18:08 | 14051 | 5.62 | ... | 12.11 | 22.313 | 12.11 |
| 2171 | 2020-03-12 23:28:08 | 14056 | 5.61 | ... | 12.11 | 22.266 | 12.11 |
| 2172 | 2020-03-12 23:38:08 | 14056 | 5.61 | ... | 12.1 | 22.25 | 12.11 |
| 2173 | 2020-03-12 23:48:08 | 14051 | 5.62 | ... | 12.1 | 22.242 | 12.09 |
| 2174 | 2020-03-12 23:58:08 | 14055 | 5.61 | ... | 12.1 | 22.188 | 12.09 |

Comment: Thank you very much for a beautiful solution to my problem. Let me work out this and come back to you.